# Use a replace in a SharePoint column

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, replace, character

I'm new on the forum and new with using jQuery too.
I try to format text like that in a SharePoint column :
I have :
text1 ; text2 ; text3

And i want :

- text1
- text2
- text3

So, i need to replace ";" character by "enter".

The type of the filed is texarea.

Someone can help me?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the code below into a script editor web part in the list view page to achieve it.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".ms-listviewtable td.ms-vb2").each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/;/g, "<br/>"));
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="test">
  Hello; this; is; a; test;
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  text = $('.test').html().replace(/;/g, "<br />");
  $('.test').html(text);
});
```